# Joi validation string exclude uri

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I'm trying to validate string parameters and I want to exclude/reject when it matches URI pattern. My current joi is `Joi.string().trim().min(2).max(30)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex` to implement your URI pattern and add `{invert: true}` to `regex` to reject it.

```
Joi.string().regex(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}$/, {invert: true})
```